# Select rows if column has same value more times

Tags: mysql, select

I have a column named `log` which contains logging information. I need a query to select all rows in which the value `today` appears two times or three times in my log column.

```
id  log
 1  today, yesterday, today, tomorrow, today 
 2  now, today, now
 3  now, today, today

Select id from table if `today` appears three times in log column
```

The id:1 will be selected

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result...

Comment: hmm and you saved them as comma-separated values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do your job:

```
select * from table where ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(log)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( log, "today", "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH("today")        
) >=3
```

Comment: oops! Sorry it was a typo. It should be log actually. I have edited the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    select * from yourtable a
    inner join (
        select max(id) as id,log,
        sum(case when log = 'today' then 1 else 0 end) as c
        from yourtable
        group by log
    ) b on b.id = a.id and b.cnt = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GROUP BY` clause with `HAVING`

```
SELECT log
FROM tbl
GROUP BY log
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```